# How to deal with the choice "other" in EntityChoiceList in Symfony2 forms?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've got a model as described below :

[image: http://yuml.me/diagram/class/[Product]0..*-1[Brand]]

I've also got a form to create a new product with a field `entity` building a dropdown list containing all the Brands.

Now I want to add a value "Other" in this list in order to allow the user to specify the Brand manually in another text field.

**The question is:** is there a clean way to manage this case (eg. adding the value "Other" in the list, which is not an entity and get the form validation to work) with Symfony2 forms?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways,

- You can subscribe for `FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA` form event. In the event method you can  create new  `Brand` object from the text, save it and set the id to the form by calling `$event->setData($data)`. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) cookbook entry.

OR

- You can append a data transformer. In its `reverseTransform` method you can create+save the object and return its id. See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) cookbook entry.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was searching around form events too and your first solution seems great in theory. The problem is that in this case, I'll have to persist a new Brand object for each form and eventually to delete it later. In the end I don't think it's the better solution. I'll take a look at the Data Transformer instead. :)

Comment: Well `FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA` event listener operates on submitted data. Before any data mapping happens. You can just check the field value is numeric or not. If not then you can save entity and set its id to the submitted data.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I've edited it to be more understandable. I want to literally add the value "Other" to the list, which is not an entity and I don't want it to be persisted. I've already figured out how to dynamically add a new Brand with collections and the "allow_add" option (And btw, FormEvents::BIND_CLIENT_DATA is deprecated since 2.1, you should use PRE_BIND instead. See http://bit.ly/JMYXih). My problem is that I don't know how to deal with a "non-entity" value in the list and how to validate it when the form comes back. Still, thanks for your feedback. :)